# Is starting with a Perl hash reference a bad way to build up a data structure?

Tags: perl, hash

A colleague wrote some Perl code (v5.30.0) that does all of this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

package main;

sub processScalarHash
{
        my $bar = $_[0];
        printf "A subroutine can access the scalar hash:  \"%s\"\n", $bar->{'key3'};
}

# Build the "Scalar Hash":
my $scalarHash = {};
$scalarHash->{'key1'} = 'dog';
$scalarHash->{'key2'} = 'cat';
$scalarHash->{'key3'} = 'fish';
bless $scalarHash;

printf "I can examine the scalar hash:\n";
print Dumper(\$scalarHash);

printf "I can access the scalar hash:  \"%s\"\n", $scalarHash->{'key1'};
my $tmpStr = 'key2';
printf "I can access the scalar hash:  \"%s\"\n", $scalarHash->{$tmpStr};

processScalarHash($scalarHash);
```

Output is:

```
me@ubuntu01$ ./ScalarHash.perl
I can examine the scalar hash:
$VAR1 = \bless( {
                   'key3' => 'fish',
                   'key1' => 'dog',
                   'key2' => 'cat'
                 }, 'main' );
I can access the scalar hash:  "dog"
I can access the scalar hash:  "cat"
A subroutine can access the scalar hash:  "fish"
me@ubuntu01$
```

I'm just learning Perl myself, and what strikes me here is that I never see any documentation about referencing hashes with scalar ($) variables.  With hash (%) and array (@) variables, yes, but never scalars ($)!  I don't know why my colleague coded like this, but I have a sinking feeling that using "scalar hashes" is a very bad practice.

Asking as a Perl newbie:  Is this bad coding?  The last thing I want to do is perpetuate bad habits that could bite me later.

Comment: It's called a "hash reference". It's documented and OK.

Comment: Might start with https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

Comment: blessing the hashref into the main package is not of any use in this example.

Comment: I don't know why the "scalar hash" name (?), but a _reference_ (what that is called) is quite like a pointer in C.   (What you have there is an anonymous hash reference.)  So references to arrays and hashes are a normal part of the language that are used freely and often.

Comment: Tip: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.

Comment: Tip: `Dumper(\$scalarHash)` should be `Dumper($scalarHash)`. That slash makes things confusing. (We use it for arrays and hashes because Dumper expects a scalar.)

Comment: [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com) is full of such examples. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ok.

---

One can't pass a hash to a sub. But one can pass a reference to a hash to a sub. So we're often working with hashes through a reference. The following is an example of this:

```perl
sub f {
   my $h = shift;                   # Ref to hash
   for my $k ( keys( %$h ) ) {
      say "$k: $h->{ $k }";
   }
}

my %h = ( a => 123, b => 456 );     # Hash
$h{ c } = 789;
f( \%h );
```

You're asking if it's ok to do work with hashes through a reference even it's not required.

```perl
my $h = { a => 123, b => 456 };     # Ref to (anon) hash
$h->{ c } = 789;
f( $h );
```

There's a performance penalty, but it's surely microscopic. The only real downside is that it makes the code a bit noisier. But not so much that it can't be overlooked. If that's ok, then absolutely go ahead and use this style.

---

That `bless` doesn't belong there, though. A `bless` outside of a constructor and blessing into `main` are both things to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Side note that won't fit in a comment: When building hashes, I try to minimize the amount of repeated code by building the hash all at once.

```
my $hash_reference = {
    key1 => 'dog',
    key2 => 'cat',
    key3 => 'fish',
};
```

instead of

```
my $scalarHash = {};
$scalarHash->{'key1'} = 'dog';
$scalarHash->{'key2'} = 'cat';
$scalarHash->{'key3'} = 'fish';
```